# iOS 7 UIView - Subview overlapping on status bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, xcode5

I created a UIView container for a registration form, inside there a a subview for login form. So navigating through "Already registered button" action

```
- (IBAction)registeredButton:(id)sender {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        _loginOverlayView.frame = self.view.frame;
    }];
}
```

My problem is basically; why subview overlapping on status bar. How can i fix it!

_loginOverlayView

[image]

p.s: Using Xcode 5, iOS7

Comment: Did you used storyboard?

Comment: @Seyhun could you post your storyboard screen?

Comment: @Zhans http://cl.ly/image/20281V2m3331 subview is hidden on board.

Comment: So you can alter your yOrigin below to 20 points

Comment: use ios 6/7 Delta in Attribute inspector.so, try to learn about how to set it. and yeah uncheck autolayout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Storyboard, in settings of your view controller check Attribution Inspector. In Extend Edges first line 'Under top bars' should be ticked

[image]

UPD:

What about 'Use Auto Layout' in File Inspector? Ticked?

[image]

UPD2:

Oh, I think you should shift down your view for 64px (20px status bar, 44px navigation controller). Coz, somehow your insets and layouts doesn't work

Comment: In iOS Programming, the basis of size unit is 'pt', not px.

Answer (score 1):

```
#define IS_IOS_7 ([[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion floatValue] < 7.0 ? NO : YES)

if (IS_IOS_7)
{
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
}
```

Comment: keyboard's skip button not working anyomore if set edgesForExtendedLayout. http://cl.ly/image/330U2Q3v2r3x

Comment: Impossible... I always use this line of code in my app. For skip button what do you mean ? "Next" ?

Comment: The "next" button doesn't work automatically. You have to implements in `UITextField` delegate methods.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 7 view's (0,0) starts from device's (0,0) i.e. inside status bar.

You can fix it either by autolayout in storyboard or code ... or you can simply add 20 pixels to the view's frame if it's iOS 7....

i.e.

```
#define ISOS_7    ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0)
```